# Reduce images size in subcaptionbox without reducing caption width

Tags: graphics

I am using `subcaptionbox` in order to have images and captions aligned since I have captions of different length. However, I am not able to reduce the size of the images. If I change width, the caption width changes too. I want to keep same width but images smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{person, shirt
\label{fig:shirtperson}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
{figures/shirtperson}}
\hfill 
\subcaptionbox{person, shirt, jacket
\label{fig:shirtjacketperson}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
{figures/shirtjacketperson}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{person, shirt, jacket, glasses\label{fig:shirtjacketglassesperson}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
{figures/shirtjacketglassesperson}}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{person, stripedshirt
\label{fig:stripedshirtperson}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
{figures/stripedshirtperson}}
\caption{Image product variants}
\label{fig:imageproductvariants}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should always provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) to your problem. An MWE (minimal working example) starts at `\documentclass` and ends at `\end{document}` including all necessary packages and lines to reproduce your issue/output, but not more than that.

Comment: Ok, I will edit the example to include them, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could surround the `\includegraphics` with a `\makebox` set to a width with `\makebox[<width>][<alignment>]{\includegraphics[<options>]{<image>}}`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{person, shirt
\label{fig:shirtperson}}
{\makebox[0.24\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]
    {example-image-a}}}
\hfill 
\subcaptionbox{person, shirt, jacket
\label{fig:shirtjacketperson}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
{example-image-b}}\hfill
\subcaptionbox{person, shirt, jacket, glasses\label{fig:shirtjacketglassesperson}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
{example-image-a}}
\hfill
\subcaptionbox{person, stripedshirt
\label{fig:stripedshirtperson}}
{\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
{example-image-b}}
\caption{Image product variants}
\label{fig:imageproductvariants}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the optional parameter '[⟨width⟩]' of `\subcaptionbox`:

```
\subcaptionbox[⟨list entry⟩]{⟨heading⟩}[⟨width⟩][⟨inner-pos⟩]{⟨contents⟩}
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{person, shirt
        \label{fig:shirtperson}}
    [.24\linewidth]
    {\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]
        {example-image}}
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{person, shirt, jacket
        \label{fig:shirtjacketperson}}
    {\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
        {example-image-a}}\hfill
    \subcaptionbox{person, shirt, jacket, glasses\label{fig:shirtjacketglassesperson}}
    {\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
        {example-image-b}}
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{person, stripedshirt
        \label{fig:stripedshirtperson}}
    {\includegraphics[width=.24\linewidth]
        {example-image-c}}
    \caption{Image product variants}
    \label{fig:imageproductvariants}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, there is already a detailed description of this in the documentation of the subcaption:

[image]

[image]